# Qt load incomplete JPEG data into QPixMap how to verify?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I have a script that displays all images found on the server and checks on a regular basis.
From time to time, it downloads an image that hasn't been completely uploaded yet resulting in a half JPEG with the lower part being gray.

I'm using a `qbyteAray` to store received data and load in in a `QPixmap` with :

```
QByteArray bytes = reply->readAll();  // bytes
qDebug() << "loading pixmap" ; 
qDebug() << pixmap.loadFromData(bytes);
```

I would like to detect if the load failed and retry 500ms later, but I cannot find a solution to verify if the pixmap contains valid JPG data.
The `loadFromData` returns TRUE but inside this method I get a Warning, this is the Application Output for the lines above:

```
loading pixmap
Corrupt JPEG data: premature end of data segment
true
```

Is there any way to check/bool if the pixmap has corrupted data?

### Solution

As suggested by vsz, if images are natural images and not graphics, it's very unlikely that pixels of the lower row are the exact gray of an invalid JPG. Thus it it possible to determine if an image is valid with these lines in a method :

```
QImage img = pixmap.toImage();
    if(  img.pixel(img.width()-1,img.height()-1 )  ==  4286611584   &&  img.pixel(img.width()/2,img.height()-1 )  ==  4286611584  &&  img.pixel(0,img.height()-1 )  ==  4286611584  ) return false; //invalid color : 4286611584  (default gray jpg)
    else return true;
```

Comment: If there is no way to do this directly (I do not use QPixMap so I do not know) a hack would be to install a message handler to grab the qDebug qCritical ... messages and handle the failure in the message handler.

Comment: Are you talking about a possible bug in Qt (the data is indeed invalid, the pixmap is cleared, but it returned true from `loadFromData`), or are you saying that the warning about "Corrupt JPEG data" is spurious?

Comment: Im saying that Qt accepts a half filled JPEG as a success

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The decoding of JPEG data happens in the external library called "libjpeg", so the Qt classes QPixmap and QImage don't do anything about it, as they receive an image which was decoded by libjpeg. If libjpeg gives an image to QPixmap, then QPixmap regards it as success.

There was a request back in 2009 for Qt to do something about it (see [this post](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/19917-Loading-corrupt-jpeg-images-with-QImage)) but it seems that nothing has been done regarding this issue.

This means that it's highly likely that you are on your own, and unless QPixmap and QImage will be expanded with new features in future releases, you can't verify the integrity of a jpeg image just by calling a method within these classes.

I would suggest one of the following:

- access libjpeg by yourself
- check the color of the last row of the image. It's unlikely that every pixel of the lowest row will be the same shade of gray as in the case of a corrupted image. This depends on your application, but if you deal with natural images (photos) then this is the solution I would advise.

Comment: it's a nice trick using the last line, If you have these lines of codes lying somewhere, could you add them to your answer?

Comment: I don't know how those pixels really look like. However, you can check them by looking at `pixmap.toImage().pixel(x,y)` in the case of a corrupted image, and then use that value later.

Comment: For info and others, the value returned by pixel is an unsigned int with a alpha channel + RGB, value of invalid jpg pixel is `4286611584` this corresponds to "FF808080" in ARGB, I'll try bottom left bottomRight and some bottomMiddle Pixels. A real image could be invalidated but is very unlikely

Comment: I admit that this suggestion of mine is a very ugly hack, the point of my answer was that Qt doesn't provide a ready solution. Accessing libjpeg directly might be more elegant, but I doubt that it would be much more future-proof.

Answer (score 4):

There are several possible messages on corrupt JPEG data:

- Corrupt JPEG data: premature end of data segment
- Corrupt JPEG data: 12 extraneous bytes before marker 0xd9
- Corrupt JPEG data: bad Huffman code

The nice vsz way would unfortunately not catch the 2 other errors I have encountered as no default gray used for these in the bad image area.
But it is better for the 1st error than what I propose below to try to report on all errors but fails in multithread.

In Qt 4.8.6, the "Corrupt JPEG data" errors were directly sent to the console, no way to catch them from qt code.
Not sure when it changed, but in Qt5.5.1, these messages go through the MessageHandler, so it is possible to catch them.

Loading only pictures from disk in the software, I use the following to know which picture is corrupted.
In the MessageHandler, I detect any "Corrupt JPEG data" message and set a global variable corrupt_jpg_detected to true.

```
if(msg.contains("Corrupt JPEG data"))
  setCorrupt_jpg_detected(&corrupt_jpg_detected, true);
```

Then in the code where I read the image, I add the following:

```
QImage img(path_to_my_image) //read image file => will sent "Corrupt JPEG data" error if image corrupted

if(corrupt_jpg_detected) "code to print in log file / inform user of image corruption, can include path_to_my_image"
```

This has a strong weakness, if you are using multithread to load pictures (using `QtConcurrent::mapped` for example) then the first of thread testing the `if(corrupt_jpg_detected)` will print image info, this will most likely not be the thread which encountered the corrupted image...